# Workflow approval inside a group

Tags: 2007, workflow, document

Working on a sharepoint workflow to a group (of 5 people), where any three of the five needs to approve or only 1 needs to reject in order for the workflow to be approved/rejected.

How do I set up the workflow so its not going to one and the then to the next a.s.o.

Any in the group should be able to reject/approve at any time within the given deadline until it reaches 3 approves or 1 reject.

The document to be approved is a Word (2010) within a simple document library in MOSS 2007